# Is present continuous justified in this case

Tags: tense, continuous

I was trying to buy something on  internet ,  I had to check out to finish .I tried to check out and it did not work. So I decided to email the seller and wrote:
"Once you have pressed the check out button , this **is appearing** " our site is not set up to accept internet payment;"

Is present continuous justified here  because  when the site is fixed we won't see this message.

Answer (score 2):

There is a better way of writing it. Present Progressive has several usages, including:

1) to describe an action starting in the past and continuing to this time.

e.g. "I'm busy right now. I'm doing my homework."

e.g. "I'm reading a great book."

2) to describe a future arrangement

e.g. "I'm having lunch with the chairman this afternoon."

3) It can be used with *if*, and *while* in dependent clauses for a future reference.

e.g. "If he's sleeping when you get there, wake him up."

What you are describing sounds like a pesky pop-up that continually reappears whenever you try to complete a payment.

*Habitual actions are best described using simple present tense.*

So, your sentence would be better written:

"*Everytime* I *press* the check out button, the pop-up "Our site is not set up to accept internet payment" *appears.*